# how to insert multiple variables into a sql query

Tags: php, sql, statements

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include('function.php');

  site::db();
  $type=$_GET['type'];
  $date=$_GET['date'];
  $amount=$_GET['amount'];

  switch($type) {
    case "in_park":
      $table = "lot_income";
      $col = "date,amount";
      $val = $date $type $amount;
      break;
  }

  $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table ($col) VALUES ('$val')");
  if(!$sql) {
    die(mysql_error());
  } 

  //header("LOCATION: dashboard.php")
?>
```

This will not work but im assuming that i will will need to explode the variables val but how to i put the comma in there too so i can put the info in many different field other than just one field.

Comment: Why do people keep using mysql_* when there have been better alternatives available for years?  Look at PDO or mysqli.  Also, you might want to read up on SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Change this..

```
$val=$date $type $amount;
```

Into this

```
$val= "'$date', '$amount'";
```

And thius

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table ($col) VALUES ('$val')");
```

into this

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table ($col) VALUES ($val)");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a column in your SQL statement:

```
$col = "date, type, amount";
```

You will need to format the SQL values accordingly:

```
$val = "'$date', '$type', '$amount'";
```

Concatenate them:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table ($col) VALUES ($val)");
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually do:

```
$table = "lot_income";

$data = array(
    'date' => "'".mysql_real_escape_string($date)."'", // date
    'type' => intval($type), // integer
    'amount' => intval($amount), // integer
    'text' => "'".mysql_real_escape_string($sometext)."'" // string
    // etc
  );

// I tend to wrap the following statement in a function for code reuse

$resource = mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO ".$table." (".implode(", ", array_keys($data).")"
    . "VALUES (".implode(", ", array_values($data).")"
   );
```

Note: for values escaping (in order to avoid SQL injections), it would be easier/safer to bind variables by using PHP extension [**PDO**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) or **mysqli**.